# C++ operator overloading: implementing + with +=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

[Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading-in-c/4421719#4421719)

shows this is done in the following way

```
class X {
  X& operator+=(const X& rhs)
  {
    // actual addition of rhs to *this
    return *this;
  }
};
inline X operator+(X lhs, const X& rhs)
{
  lhs += rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

I understand why the argument `lhs` needs to be taken by value, but why do we need to return it by value? I mean, what's the problem with the following:

```
inline X& operator+(X lhs, const X& rhs)
{
  lhs += rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

Inside the function, `lhs` is a new `X` and modifying it does not affect any of the two operands. Since this is new, we can return it via reference, right?

Comment: that would become undefined becaus you cant return a local by reference

Comment: @Koushik you could engineer it so that it doesn't. But the point is that it would not make any sense.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes you are right. But the point of the code is about return by value. it will also help in move semantics in the case of `operator +`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of returning a reference to a local object is that the caller will receive something that is already dead on arrival.

When you exit from a function all locals are destroyed, so you cannot keep using references to them.

Code like

```
const X& res = a+b;
```

would works if the operator returns by value because there is a specific rule in the language that says that temporary objects bound to references will be kept alive until the reference itself is destroyed.

Returning a reference instead is different because the lifetime of the object is a responsibility of the called operator, not of the caller. So the end result will be a reference that is bound to an object that has already been destroyed.

Even just

```
X res;
res = a+b;
```

would not work, because when the operator call returns the object is destroyed before the assignment is made to `res`. Same would be in case of a copy constructor `X res = a+b;`.

Answer (score 0):

**Never** return ba reference if the value you are referencing will cease to exist after exiting the function.

In this case, `lhs` will exist until the function returns. If you return by reference, that reference will "point" to a value that is no more, and any attempt to use it will result in undefined behavior.

That's the reason for return by value. But no worries, many compilers can optimize the additional copy away, and it is in fact no copy but a move operation, so even if it's not optimized away, "heavy" object will be moved and not copied since C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly answering the question, but to aid understanding about references ... be very cautious about returning a reference, except if you **know** the referent (object being referred to) is stable.

It is unsafe to do this

```
const std::string& doNothing(const std::string& x) {return x;}
```

You will become unstuck on the second call shown below

```
std::string baa = "sheep";
std::cout << doNothing(baa) << std::endl;    // works
std::cout << doNothing("goat") << std::endl; // UNSAFE
```

This is because the second call involves the implicit creation of a temporary object (of type std::string using constructor call `string("goat")`)

By contrast, it is safe to return a reference from `name()`

```
class Person
{
  private: std::string _name;
  public: const std::string& name() { return _name; }
  // other constructors and ways to set a _name
};
```

One can be reasonably assured that the class object (and therefore its internal `_name`) will stick around long enough for the reference to be useful to the caller.